# How to pass variable to SQL in Python

Tags: python

I have a python script like the below. It will receive parameters and will query in DB. However I am not sure how to pass the variable `abcd` to the SQL statements mentioned below.

> abcd = sys.argv[3]

```
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ticket WHERE "
               "status <> 'closed' AND version = 'abcd'  AND id IN (%s)" % ','.join(tickets))
```

I tried different options with %s. But all throwing syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can find examples of how to run raw SQL statements with parameters in the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)

I think this approach will be helpful to you:

```
cursor = db.cursor() 
cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ticket WHERE status <> 'closed' AND version = 'abcd' AND id IN (%s)", [','.join(tickets)])
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation errors? Is this code inside a function?

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT 2021: Do what you must do, but don't follow this suggestion from ~7 years ago. See comment below.**

I think you need to get the [string formating](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) right.

Try something like this:

```
query = "SELECT count(id) FROM ticket WHERE version = %(version)s and id IN %(tpl)s" % {'version': 1, 'tpl': (1, 2, 3, 4)}

cursor.execute(query)
```

Comment: Please never suggest string interpolation for a SQL-query. This is a **huge security issue** and should never be recommended. Most libraries has a way to pass in parameters as a *parameterized query*. Even if this in theory would be secure since you're not using user generated data, it's an unnecessary risk and all usages of it should always come with **a huge warning** about it!

Comment: Right you are. Thanks for pointing it out. I was even more clueless at that time than I am now!